# How to access rootElement from SVGDocument?

Tags: typescript, svg

I parse an SVG to get an SVG document.

```
const containerElement = window.document.querySelector(containerSelector);
const svgDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(svg, "image/svg+xml");
```

I can access `svgDocument.rootElement` in the browser to get the svg element.

But when I try to access the property from TypeScript

```
const svgElement = svgDocument.rootElement
```

I get a message that

```
Property 'rootElement' does not exist on type 'Document'.
```

What am I missing here? Is `rootElement` not a standardized attribute of `Document/SVGDocument`?

Comment: Document IS the root element.

Comment: rootElement is deprecated/dead try [svgDocument.documentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement)